# Set ConnectionKeepAliveStrategy for the HttpClientBuilder via @ConfigurationProperties

Tags: java, spring

I am able to set certain properties (e.g. maxConnTotal) for the HttpClientBuilder as below:

yaml

```
http.client.max-conn-total: 10
```

java

```
@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "http.client")
public HttpClientBuilder httpClientBuilder() {
  return HttpClientBuilder.create();
}
```

I'm hoping there's a way to also set the ConnectionKeepAliveStrategy as I need to use a custom one.

Ideally I can just define the ConnectionKeepAliveStrategy as a regular bean which if missing it would simply leave the http client builder unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't realise it's that easy...

I just need to add the following to my config:

```
@Autowired(required = false)
public void customizeHttpClientBuilder(HttpClientBuilder httpClientBuilder, ConnectionKeepAliveStrategy keepAliveStrategy) {
  httpClientBuilder.setKeepAliveStrategy(keepAliveStrategy);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

And an even simpler way using `java.util.Optional`:

```
@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "http.client")
public HttpClientBuilder httpClientBuilder(Optional<ConnectionKeepAliveStrategy> keepAliveStrategy) {
    HttpClientBuilder builder = HttpClientBuilder.create();
    keepAliveStrategy.ifPresent(builder::setKeepAliveStrategy);
    return builder;
}
```